# First curly brace of functions

Tags: c

I keep getting:

> Expected identifier or '(' "

I've re-started the project, modeled after my old homework assignments that have used functions and am unable to alleviate the issue. Any and all suggestions/recommendations are welcomed after 2 days of stressing on this.

Here's the beginning of my code to just before main. I can include more if needed. Many thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* constants */
#define STD_HOURS 40.0 /* hours per week */
#define SIZE 5 /* employees to process */
#define OT 1.5 /* for overtime calculation */
#define AVERAGE 5 /* for obtaining averages */

/* function to obtain hours worked for employees */
void getHours (long int clock_number[]);
float hours_worked[]; /* array for hours worked */
{
    printf("Enter the number of hours worked for employee #%d: ", d + 1);
    scanf("%f", &hours_worked[d]);
    return (getHours);
}

/* function call to calculate overtime hours */
void overtime_grosspay (float hours_worked[]);
float d; /* overtime calculation variable */
float hourly_wage[];  /* initialize array */
float hours_worked[];   /* array for hours worked */
float overtime_hours[]; /* array for overtime pay */
float gross_pay[];  /* array for gross pay per employee */
{
    overtime_hours[d] = hours_worked[d] - STD_HOURS;
    gross_pay[d] = hourly_wage[d] * STD_HOURS + (hourly_wage[d] * overtime_hours[d] * OT);
    return (overtime_grosspay);
}


/* function call to calculate gross pay */
void regular_grosspay (float hours_worked[]);
float d; /* regular gross variable */
float hourly_wage[];  /* initialize array */
float hours_worked[];   /* array for hours worked */
float overtime_hours[]; /* array for overtime pay */
float gross_pay[];  /* array for gross pay per employee */
{
    overtime_hours[d] = 0;
    gross_pay[d] = hours_worked[d] * hourly_wage[d];
    return (regular_grosspay);
}

/* function call to print */



int main()
{
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
/* function to obtain hours worked for employees */
void getHours (long int clock_number[]);
float hours_worked[]; /* array for hours worked */
{
    printf("Enter the number of hours worked for employee #%d: ", d + 1);
    scanf("%f", &hours_worked[d]);
    return (getHours);
}
```

The `void getHours(…)` line ends with a semicolon; that is a function declaration.

The `float hours_worked[];` line is an array definition, but it doesn't specify the array size and is not prefixed with `extern` so it is invalid.

The `{` therefore has no business in the code; it isn't part of a function definition.

As a function definition, there's no `d` in scope, and returning a pointer to the function isn't going to work (wrong type, amongst other things — the function isn't supposed to return a value at all!), and there's no way to make the data available to the calling code.

You probably need:

```
/* function to obtain hours worked for one employee */
float getHours (long clock_number)
{
    float hours_worked;
    printf("Enter the number of hours worked for employee #%ld: ", clock_number);
    scanf("%f", &hours_worked);
    return (hours_worked);
}
```

There will then be changes required to how you use this function.  I've not even looked at the code beyond it.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, your answer is putting me on the right track. Getting rest of code caught up accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following:

```
void getHours (long int clock_number[]);
float hours_worked[]; /* array for hours worked */
{
```

to:

```
void getHours (long int clock_number[])
{
float hours_worked[]; /* array for hours worked */
```

(notice how in addition to moving the { the ; after the function declaration has been removed)

Comment: That's a good start — it is by no means all the problems in the function (the moved array definition isn't going to compile, even, let alone the lines after it using all sorts of variables that aren't defined).

Comment: @SoronelHaetir  Xcode keeps insisting that the ; be added after the top level declarator. I do appreciate you responding though. Very cool community in here.